# TableView edit column JAVA FX

Tags: java, oracle, javafx

i am creating a TableView in java FX and i'm trying to make a column editable . this is my code for the column name in the table :

```
 TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");

    name.setMinWidth(150);

    name.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Phone,String>("name")
    );
    name.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

    name.setOnEditCommit( new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Phone,String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Phone,String> t) {
           ((Phone) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
            ).setName(t.getNewValue());
        }
    });
```

i have 2 errors saying cannot find getTableView() and getTablePosition()
i followed the oracle tutorial [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE)

Thx for your help.

Comment: Show please stack trace ....

Comment: note that the tutorial is ... suboptimal as it does not expose the internally used properties: if it would, there would be no need for a custom edit handler, the default would take care ..

Answer (score 4):

You almost certainly have the wrong import. Make sure you are importing

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent ;
```

You should also avoid using raw types; i.e. you should replace

```
TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
```

with

```
TableColumn<Phone, String> name = new TableColumn<>("name");
```

(and similarly make sure you use `TableView<Phone>` if you are not doing so already).

Comment: Thank you bro! that was it !