# JAVA FX ObservableList cannot initialise

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

i am creating a TableView in JAVA FX and i have a class Phone to represent my data like the documentation said .
the phone class has a SimpleStringProperty phoneName.
in the documentation they make the class phone static and the property final.
if i make the class static i have an error modifier static not allowed here
if i make the property final i can't create setters but in the doc they do

and in my application when a create an ObservableList of phones , when i put data in it like below :

```
 private ObservableList<Phone> phoneList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(          
        new Phone( "iphone" , "ios")  ,
        new Phone("nexus" , "android") 
          );
```

i have an error saying : cannot convert String to SimpleStringProperty

Thx u . not that if i remove the static and final keywords and change the properties to normal String , it works but i'am having problems after when i want to make the table editable like i explain here [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345935/tableview-edit-column-java-fx)

Thx u guys

Comment: I am going to guess that your problem is in the constructor of your `Phone` class.

Comment: Does your constructor follow this pattern? `private Person(String fNamel) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);`

Answer (score 2):

The Song constructor need to look like this :

```
public Song(String model,String os){

this.model = new SimpleStringProperty(model);
this.os = new SimpleStringProperty(os);

}
```

You need to create the SimpleStringProperty with your string.

Comment: Thx u bro, its working but can you tell me the difference between SimpleStringProperty and a normal String ? why do we use it here ?

Comment: When you use properties, if the value of a property in the datamodel changes, the view of the item in the TableView is automatically updated to match the updated data model value. If a normal String had been used, the TableView would not be refreshed because it would not be aware of the value changes.